# Запрет регистрации пользователей с одинаковым email

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте.
В общем вопрос описан в заголовке.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Через SQL запрос проверяешь, перед тем как добавить в БД, нет ли такого пользователя, сравниваешь на нижнем регистре логин, если есть - редирект на страницу ошибки, если нет - добавляешь в БД.

Comment: Спасибо конечно)
Я хочу узнать, можно ли это реализовать при помощи каких-либо настроек)
Как реализовать подручными средствами, я могу придумать)

Answer (score 2):

- Используйте `django 1.5` со своей моделью юзера.
- Проверяйте существование перед созданием (возможно пропатчив метод save оригинальной модели)
- Манкипатчинг оригинальной модели где указать для поля `email` свойство `unique=True`

Я бы рекомендовал первое, т.к. релиз 1.5 дышит в спину (странно что вообще ещё не вышел).

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно использовать [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/), с регистрацией через формочку RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

Comment: Которая собственно и проверяет существование мыла в БД :)